# UWP App Crashes when populating an ObservableCollection<MyClass> in OnNavigatedTo()

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection

this is a very weird crash I think.

The UWP app fails "sometimes" when FirstPage is selected. This page has an AdaptativeGridView where each item is a FlipView. The ItemsSource of all FlipViews is the same, a unique ObservableCollection in code-behind.

UI capture example: [ui-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDm3R.png)

The issue is happening in UWP apps, in the async version of OnNavigatedTo() method, when you load data in an ObservableCollection.

In case you use a fully sync OnNavigatedTo() to load the ObservableCollection, I haven't seen the issue so far.

The output error is:

```
'Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.29301.2_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x39c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3284 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.29301.2_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.29301.2_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.29301.2_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.ObjectModel.dll
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.ObjectModel.dll but was not handled in user code
The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000B)

'Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET
```

The stacktrace is:

```
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.Pages.FirstPage.FillFlipViewData(List`1 filenames) in C:\Users\**\source\repos\Sol.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest\Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest\Pages\FirstPage.xaml.cs:line 71
   at Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.Pages.FirstPage.<OnNavigatedTo>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\**\source\repos\Sol.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest\Proj.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest\Pages\FirstPage.xaml.cs:line 61
```

The code-behind is:

```
    public sealed partial class FirstPage : Page
    {

        public ObservableCollection<MyAdaptativeGridViewItem> AdaptativeGridViewData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyAdaptativeGridViewItem>()
        {
            new MyAdaptativeGridViewItem(1, "Item 1"),
            new MyAdaptativeGridViewItem(2, "Item 2"),
            new MyAdaptativeGridViewItem(3, "Item 3"),
            new MyAdaptativeGridViewItem(4, "Item 4"),
        };

        public ObservableCollection<MyFlipViewItem> FlipViewData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyFlipViewItem>();

        public FirstPage()
        {
            // Note that every time we navigate to this Page
            // the full class is instantiated from scratch
            // Hence, the constructor is always executed
            // and all properties are initialized
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Async version
        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            // Get in a List<string> all image locations
            var filenames = await LoadDataAsync();

            // This function generates the FlipViewData ObservableCollection
            // that is binded to the UI
            FillFlipViewData(filenames);
        }

        private void FillFlipViewData(List<string> filenames)
        {
            // Note that each time .Add() is used in a ObservableCollection
            // the UI "is notified" of the change
            for (int i = 0; i < filenames.Count; i++)
            {
                var name = filenames[i];
                FlipViewData.Add(new MyFlipViewItem(i, "/Assets/Images/" + name));
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<string>> LoadDataAsync()
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            string absPath = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path
                + "\\Assets\\Images";
            var storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(absPath);
            var files = await storageFolder.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (var f in files)
                result.Add(f.Name);

            return result;
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

The UI is:

```
    <Page.Resources>

        <Thickness x:Key="MediumLeftRightMargin">24,0,24,0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="XSmallLeftTopRightBottomMargin">8, 8, 8, 8</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="XXSmallTopMargin">0, 4, 0, 0</Thickness>

        <x:Double x:Key="MediumFontSize">16</x:Double>

        <Style x:Key="BodyTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource MediumFontSize}" />
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Name="FlipView_ItemTemplate" x:DataType="models:MyFlipViewItem">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageLocation, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="AdaptativeGridView_ItemTemplate" x:DataType="models:MyAdaptativeGridViewItem">
            <Grid x:Name="itemThumbnail"
                  Padding="{StaticResource XSmallLeftTopRightBottomMargin}"
                  Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}">

                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    <FlipView Width="150" Height="150"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlipView_ItemTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ThisPrincipalPage, Path=FlipViewData, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                    <TextBlock
                                Margin="{StaticResource XXSmallTopMargin}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextStyle}"
                                Text="{x:Bind PresetName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>


    </Page.Resources>


    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea" Margin="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}">
        <Grid
            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush}">
            <!--
                The SystemControlPageBackgroundChromeLowBrush background represents where you should place your content. 
                Place your content here.
            -->
            <StackPanel>

                <GridView
                Padding="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AdaptativeGridView_ItemTemplate}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind AdaptativeGridViewData, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectionMode="None"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Feel free to find the code [here](https://github.com/oddikaro/Sol.UWP.Blank.NavigationTest.git) and test it.

**Extra observations:**

- In the github project you will have a fully sync version (just comment/uncomment the region to test it).
- In the sync version the code never fails, and UI state when the items are added (just before FlipViewData.Add()) looks always like a blank content.

[UI-unloaded-in-aync-and-sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqXCL.png)

However, in the async version, the UI sometimes is blank and sometimes is partially loaded like:

[UI-partially-loaded-in-async](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xNj6.png)

I have noticed that the issue only happens when we add items in this UI state.

- The error always happens after adding the first item to FlipViewData.

[Visual-Studio-capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBNI8.png)

**Final though:**

Maybe, this suggest some incogruent data (the collection has "different" number of items depending on who is looking like a threading issue) when the ObservableColletion tries to notify the change after FlipViewData.Add(). However, the addition is happening in the UI Thread.

**Alternative**

There are several alternatives to make the same UI without the described issue. This is not what I want to find. However, one of the approaches might give some extra light into the described issue. Specifically, in the described approach, the GridView is binded to an ObservableCollection, and each GridView item is itselft binded to another ObervableCollection. Both ObservableCollections are two different Properties in the code-behind.

The described error does not seem to happen if the data model is redefined consisting in a single Property in the code-behind, i.e., a *nested ObservableCollection*, i.e.,

the new data model

```
    public class MyGridViewItem
    {
        public int PresetIndex { get; set; }
        public string PresetName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<MyFlipViewItem> FlipViewData { get; set; }
    }
```

and the single Property in code-behind

```
public ObservableCollection<MyGridViewItem> GridViewData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyGridViewItem>();
```

With this approach, and using x:Bind in all the bindings in the XAML file (no longer classic Binding needed), the issue does not seem to appear.

Therefore, it seems the **nested ObservableCollection is working fine** but using two separate ObservableCollections (one for the root UI GridView element, and another separate for the child UI FlipView elements) is not. Maybe this is related with the notes in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0):

> ObservableCollection must be the root element, because the
> x:TypeArguments attribute that must be used to specify the constrained
> type of the generic ObservableCollection is only supported on the
> object element for the root element.

Comment: "a runtime error occurs" - what's the error? Are you getting an Exception with a full stack trace?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Thank you Broots, I have updated the question with all the error info I see. The issue happens "sometimes". The error suggests some threading issue.

Comment: I have checked your sample, there are methods named LoadData() and LoadDataAsync() in your PresetsViewModel.cs, and ImageLocationsService class achieved the GetImageLocationsAsync() and GetImageLocations() method. You mentioned “**if I load everything syncronously it works fine**”, you mean if you use LoadData() and it works well, if you use LoadDataAsync() method, an exception will be thrown, right ? Or the error is related to GetImageLocationsAsync() and GetImageLocations() method.

Comment: Could you please explain “**load synchronously**” in detail? Will this problem also happen if you use LoadData() and GetImageLocationsAsync()?

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Thank you Arya for taking the time to check the code! Yes, if I run ViewModel.LoadData() in the constructor of PresetsPage, the app works fine. This method, in turn, will call "the sync version" of GetImageLocations(), which, in turn, calls "the sync version" of GetAllRelativePaths, which basically calls System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path), which is sync. ViewModel.LoadDataAsync() cannot be used in the constructor (I remarked that because I am learning), so if I want to try the Async flow, I use LoadDataAsync() in OnNavigatedTo(). This is where the issue happens.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Note also that the Async flow use a different approach for obtaining filenames. It uses what it is recommended in UWP apps. So, ideally, the async path should be LoadDataAsync() -> GetImageLocationsAsync() -> GetAllRelativePathsAsync() which internally calls "await StorageFolder" methods. For debuging purposes, I just put all this code directly in LoadDataAsync() and commented the line "var data = await _imageLocationsService.GetImageLocationsAsync();". So we only need to inspect LoadDataAsync() with the code in the question. That code fails sometimes when FlipViewData.Add() run

Comment: I have tested your LoadDataAsync() method in a new uwp app, it works well. So this issue might not be related to the above code, could you please try to test the async method in a new blank app(Universal Windows) instead of the Windows Template Studio project and the new MVVM Standard?

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Thank you a lot for taking the time to check the issue! As stated in the question, I tested the same code in a blanck UWP App and worked. I re-tested it again with code-behind and also with a basic ViewModel class and the issue is not present. This is why I don't see the real issue here. I also tried to eliminate the dependency of the Core project for the models and service used in that Page and the issue still appears...

Comment: We have tested your sample. When we use InitializeBasicAsync(), we got behavior is that the code works well, but images don’t appear in UI, which might be related to the way to call async method. So my suggestion is that you could create a PresetsViewModel(), and then call “**await InitializeBasicAsync()**” when loading the created model.

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Thank you Arya for your suggestions and the time to check this issue. I have made a significant update in the question. It seems some issue related to updating an ObservableCollection inside the async version of OnNavigatedTo()...

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Well, not really. The issue is still happening. An answer is not another way of doing the same UI. An answer is why this error is happening. My question is not "how to" is "why this". The question is more for curiosity, since it is very weird.